# What does it mean to replace slashes (/) by exclamation marks (!) in a substitute command?

Tags: substitute

I recently saw a substitute command where the author had the `/` replaced by a `!` like this: `:s!abc!ABC!g`

I tried to find some documentation on this usage but I couldn't find anything relevant. So I tried to experiment by myself and once again I couldn't figure out the real difference between the two signs. Here's what I found:

- It's not possible to mix `!` and `/` in a command. For example `:s!abc/ABC` fails.
- It may be useful to use `!` to avoid escaping a `/`in a pattern. For example if I want to replace `</` with `%` I can use `:%s!</!%!g` instead of `:%s/<\//%/g`.
- It seems that in some case some regex won't work with `/` and works properly with `!` but as I'm not really a regex expert i'm not sure of that.

So my question is simple: What is the advantage of using `!` in a substitute command and when should I decide to use it instead of `/`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From [`:help :global`](http://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#E148):

> Instead of the '/' which surrounds the `{pattern}`, you can use any other
> single byte character, but not an alphabetic character, '', '"' or '|'.
> This is useful if you want to include a '/' in the search pattern or
> replacement string.

Also see [`:help pattern-delimiter`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#pattern-delimiter).

As you already devised from your experimentation, this is to prevent the so-called "[leaning toothpick syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)". Consider this:

```
:%s/\/home\/martin\/test/\/home\/jake\/x/
```

versus:

```
:%s!/home/martin/test!/home/jake/x!
```

The second form is obviously a lot more readable. I prefer to use `!` or `|` for this as it's the most similar to `/`, but other prefer `@`, `#`, `^`, or something else.

This is the only reason you can change the delimiter; to make it more readable for us humans. The computer doesn't care.

Some other programs are even more flexible by the way, in GNU sed for example you can use `x` as delimiter if you wanted. `sed sxaxbxg file` is the same as `sed s/a/b/g file`, although I don't think that's especially readable.