# What is the syntax if I want to replace one directory with another in vim given that I have '/' in it?

Tags: substitute, replace

If I have this directory: `/home/abc/def/apples/`

and I want to replace it with this directory: `/home/nfl/nfl/nba/` in vim,

what is the syntax? I tried using `%s/a/b/g` but this command fails.

Answer (score 4):

You can escape the `/` with a backslash (`\`):

```
:%s/\/path\/name/\/new\/path/g
```

This is usually okay if you have just one or two `/`s, but it quickly becomes very unwieldy. A better option is to [use a different delimiter](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3156/51):

```
:%s!/path/name!/new/path!g
```