# Replace a line with two other lines

Tags: substitute, replace

I have multiple files with a string like:

```
source /PATH/TO/OLD/ENV.sh
```

And this needs to be replaced with:

```
source /PATH/TO/NEW/ENV1.sh
source /PATH/TO/NEW/ENV2.sh
```

Usually, I use `sed`  to replace strings. What's the 'vim-way' of doing this?
Thanks.

Comment: Vim's `:substitute` command is incredibly similar to sed's. See `:h :s`. For multiple files, see `:h :argdo` and `:h bufdo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\r` to represent a newline in `:substitute` patterns:

```
:%s,source /PATH/TO/OLD/ENV.sh,source /PATH/TO/NEW/ENV1.sh\rsource /PATH/TO/NEW/ENV2.sh/,
```

Note that in substitute patterns `\n` means NULL byte, not newline. This is inconsistent and confusing (I'm not sure what the reason for it is, it's a vi quirk you'll just have to remember)

I used `,` instead of `/` to avoid having to escape all the `/`s in the path; see [What does it mean to replace slashes (/) by exclamation marks (!) in a substitute command?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3156/51)

You can use the `:bufdo`, `:windo`, and `:tabdo` commands to run any command on multiple buffers, windows, or tabs. For example:

```
:bufdo :%s,source /PATH/TO/OLD/ENV.sh,source /PATH/TO/NEW/ENV1.sh\rsource /PATH/TO/NEW/ENV2.sh,
:wa
```

Which should do what you want.