# How to escape forward slashes?

Tags: substitute, escape

I was editing a file and found accidentally that I somehow escaped all the forward slashes in a path I was replacing in text. And that is something very useful!

For instance, to do this replacement correctly I should escape the second path:

```
:%s/mvn//opt/maven/bin/mvn/g
```

I did that somehow with an accidental keystroke! But which one? :-(

Thank you.

Comment: Related issue: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3156/what-does-it-mean-to-replace-slashes-by-exclamation-marks-in-a-substitut

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to escape them: you could use a different separator for the search pattern and the replace part:

```
%s;mvn;/opt/maven/bin/mvn;g
```

But, if you really want to escape them, you can use a backslash (`\`):

```
%s/mvn/\/opt\/maven\/bin\/mvn/g
```

(much harder to read, IMO)