# What's the meaning of the two question marks in substitution operation?

Tags: substitute

I'm learning how substitution works in Vim. And I find this example really weird to understand: `:?a?,/b/s/bad/good`. I know what this command will do in general. But why use two question marks to wrap `a`? What does it mean?

Comment: @MartinTournoij I could be wrong but isn't it a bit different? Here the `?` are in the range section of the command and if I understand [`:h :range`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3Arange) properly they reference to `?{pattern}[?] the previous line where {pattern} matches` which is not the same thing as what I asked in the question you linked.

Comment: Oops sorry, you're right @statox; I was in a hurry and misread the question 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command is composed of two parts:

```
:?a?,/b/            The range 
        s/bad/good  The substitution command
```

You probably already know that the `:s` command can take a range:

- `:s/bad/good` will do the substitution on the current line
- `:%s/bad/good` will do the substitution on all the lines of the buffer
- And `/pattern1/,/pattern2/s/bad/good` will perfom the substitution between the next line matching `pattern1` and the next one matching `pattern2`.

The help [`:h :range`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3Arange) gives us the different items we can use as a range:

```
Line numbers may be specified with:     *:range* *{address}*
    {number}    an absolute line number
    .       the current line              *:.*
    $       the last line in the file         *:$*
    %       equal to 1,$ (the entire file)        *:%*
    't      position of mark t (lowercase)        *:'*
    'T      position of mark T (uppercase); when the mark is in
            another file it cannot be used in a range
    /{pattern}[/]   the next line where {pattern} matches     *:/*
    ?{pattern}[?]   the previous line where {pattern} matches *:?*
    \/      the next line where the previously used search
            pattern matches
    \?      the previous line where the previously used search
            pattern matches
    \&      the next line where the previously used substitute
            pattern matches
```

Take a particular note of `?{pattern}[?]   the previous line where {pattern} matches`: this is what is used in your question.

Your command `:?a?,/b/s/bad/good` will be applied to the lines between the previous line matching `a` and the next one matching `b`. To make the difference clear between `//` and `??` here are two examples:

Take this file:

```
a
bad
b
bad
a
```

With you cursor on `b` in line 3 if you use `:?^a$?,/^b$/s/bad/good` you will get:

```
a
good
b
bad
a
```

Because line 1 is the previous one matching `?^a$?` and line 3 is the next one matching `/^b$/`

Now if you use `:/^a$/,/^b$/s/bad/good` you will get

```
a
bad
b
good
a
```

Because the next line matching `/^a$/` is line 5 and Vim know how to reverse the inverted ranges.

---

Note that in the range part of the command changing `//` to `??` changes how the action behave. This is different than changing the `/` characters in the substitution part of the command where `s/bad/good/`, `s?bad?good?` and `s;bad;good` are all equivalent as explained in [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3156/1841).